# asciidoctor increase toc width

Tags: css, asciidoctor

I'm rewriting the documentation of [AssertJ](https://assertj.github.io/doc/) in asciidoc and I'd like to increase the width of the TOC and the overall width of the content (to fill up empty area)

I looked into asciidoctor.css and found that I could increase this property from the toc2 width from 20 to 25em but it messes up the

```css
  #toc.toc2 {
    /* initially 20em */
    width: 25em
  }

  #header,
  #content,
  #footnotes,
  #footer {
  width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    /* initially 75em,  increasing it to 100em does not play with toc when toc is increased */
    max-width: 100em;
    *zoom: 1;
    position: sticky;
    padding-left: .9375em;
    padding-right: .9375em
  }
```

I'm happy this the new TOC width but the problem is that when reducing the window the content is hidden by the TOC as shown in the screenshot :(

I'm no web developer, I have tried a few things without success, could help me setting this correctly or pointing to good resources to do so ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the css at two places.

```css
body.toc2 {
   padding-left: 26em;
}

#toc.toc2 {
    /* initially 20em */
    width: 25em;
}
```

The one for the body will be `1em` extra then the width you want.

**Results**

[image: Results]